# generate barcodes with crud information in python

Tags: python, django, postgresql, crud, barcode

This is a control access for builders with double check to enter the work area, first with the official ID then the barcode to verify the information.

I already built a CRUD application using Python, Django and Postgresql without the barcode because still don't know how to connect the data with the EAN code.

How can I connect this information with the codebar to show on modal window?

Comment: What is "a crud"?

Comment: What difficulty do you have with including one more information in your database?

Comment: I didn't understand if you want to *create* a barcode or if you want to *read* it, or what else you want to do with it.

Comment: Create, Read,Update and Delete actions. Sorry for the bad english, I'm not native

Comment: I tried to reword this part a bit. Does it make sense?

Comment: Want to read it, I'll create the barcode manually. Just for the moment, later I'll generate lots of barcode with a seed.

Comment: So your question is how to read a barcode?

Comment: Basically, yes. Read it and show information required.

Comment: The title of the question says "generate barcodes". I think that's a bit misleading then.

Comment: To read the barcode you will need some sort of scanner.

Comment: Already have one. I tested with some barcodes, everything fine, next step is to read the barcode and fill the fields with the builder information. Still stuck with that part

Comment: Well assuming the scanner is of the keyboard wedge type, then having the user navigate to the input field and scan the barcode will enter the decoded data into the field. From there it is up to you as whether that data is automatically dealt with or the user has to take some action e.g. click a button to process it.